# Changing Swing progress bar look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jprogressbar

I keep trying to chang the UIManager to make these stupid looking green squares go away.  how do i change the look and feel of this to the user?  Is it system dependent?  Someone else who was compiling my code had a constant gradient.  Ideally, it would just be a solid square, as opposed to smaller blocks.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Netbeans? That's just an IDE. Don't you mean Swing?

Comment: Yes.  I use netbeans as the editor and mention it in case there was an easy way to set it up in there.  But would be nice to be able to change/customize the progress bar only (and not the entire app) look and feel

Comment: It sounds like as if you were asking how to change look'n'feel of Netbeans. This makes no sense. That's the same as asking how to change the look'n'feel of Notepad. I've edited the title+tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting it to the system's (user's) look and feel?

The easiest way to set the look and feel is by launching the GUI after calling:

```
try
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // ...
}
```

With that said, the above appears to be the Windows XP theme and may indeed be the system (user) theme. I generally stay away from custom themes in GUIs unless there is a *very* good reason (e.g., customer/user requirement).

That is to say, the above code makes it system dependent, which is *good* because it matches the user's expecations.

Comment: I have tried it and works (which is the default.)  The old schoole java one looks outdated, but did change the progress Bar.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Wanted to add that the important note in pickypg's entry is to write the command before the app is loaded.  I tried after the app was loaded but before shown, and it wasn't working.  For additional customization, piesnikowski's answer below is an example.

Answer (score 2):

"These stupid looking green squares" are element of Windows XP's Look nad Feel. If you want them to look different, you can change Look and Feel for this particular component.

Just use below workaround:

```
try {
    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(/* Look and Feel for your JProgressBar*/);
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

MyProgressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

try {
    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(/* Previous, main Look and Feel */);
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I'm using this code for giving JFileChooser another look and it works perfectly.

You just change Look and Feel before creating component, and restoring previous one, just after that creation.

Comment: Works great thanks! I would not have thought something like this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Code below change the L&F of entire JFrame.

```
static Main m;//Reference to JFrame to be updated
static String maxOSLookAndFeel = "ch.randelshofer.quaqua.QuaquaLookAndFeel";//Package of particular L&F    
private void MacOSLFjMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_MacOSLFjMenuItemActionPerformed
                    // TODO add your handling code here:
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(maxOSLookAndFeel);
                                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(m);
                                m.validate();
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }//GEN-LAST:event_MacOSLFjMenuItemActionPerformed
```

**Secundo:**
In my opinion (googled a lot and by expirience) it's impossible to affect only one JComponent while you attach a new L&F. You change your L&F in entire JFrame or you can [Write your own Swing Component.](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html)

Another way to achive your goal is studying java [source code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and find place where JProgressBar image is beeing added to component and override this method by extending JProgressBar.

Comment: okay.  I assume I would have to download this look and feel and get everything setup to make it look like a mac, which I guess would change the look of my entire app, but really just looking into possibly changing only my progress bar.

Comment: Klepoatra you've got right. It was C&P from my project but now I edited my post as best I can. Cheers!:)

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive description of Java look and feel could be found by Sun Java document, here: [Java, Look and Feel Design Guidelines](http://messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/JLFDG05.pdf) in pdf.